# How to show loading dialog using DialogFragment in koush/ion

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I has written a custom `HttpUtil` using ion(version 2.1.6) like this:
code snippet:

```
HttpUtil.get(Context ctx, boolean showProgress, String url, Map<String, String> params, Class<T> returnObj).setCallback(new HttpResponseCallback<T>(Context ctx) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(T result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(Exception e, T result) {
    }
});
```

HttpResponseCallback is my custom response callback. When using it, should implement `onSuccess() & onFail` method.

When `HttpUtil.get()` is called, I want to show a loading dialog automatically and when the request is finished, the dialog also should be closed automatically.

(I mean when using `HttpUtil.get()`, user do not need to open dialog and close dialog manually.)

I went thought koush/ion, it had `progressDialog()` method, but I didn't found any method which using `DialogFragment()`.

How do I implement this?

PS: I'm using v4 support library.

The package of DialogFragment is "android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment"

Answer (score 0):

[can you see this link that is helpful for you](https://gist.github.com/dhawalhshah/1355547)

you can also use ProgressDialog into that method onSuccess and onFail...

```
       progressDialogLoading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "","", true);
                progressDialogLoading.show();
                progressDialogLoading.setCancelable(true);
```